# Swift: How to get the value from a AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?> from a NSScanner?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift

I don't know how to use the AutoreleasingUnsafePointer. I have the following code:

```
var myString: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?>

myScanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet(), intoString: myString)
```

Now, what should I do to get the string from 'myString'? I know it can be nil, but I couldn't figure out a way to get the string value in case it wasn't nil. And the Swift unwrapping technique just only works with the Optional type.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `myString` the same as `storingString`?

Comment: What you are saying is a little off. If `myString` is not defined as an optional (not having the `?` syntax in definition), then it **cannot** be `nil` and can be accessed directly (no need to unwrap with `!`). If `myString` is optional, then it can be `nil`, so you need to check first, then you need to unwrap it (with `!`)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes storingString was the same as myString. I forgot to reedit my code.

Comment: @Emilie. You're right, dasblinkenlight made an example in his answer. However, declaring the var as AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?> still works by using the Jack Wu the solution, but it's longer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the second parameter of `scanUpToCharactersFromSet` is declared as autoreleasing unsafe pointer, i.e. `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?>` you should be able to invoke your function without making a pointer explicitly. Swift lets you use `&` operator on an `NSString?` variable to produce an autoreleasing unsafe pointer, like this:

```
var str : NSString? = nil
myScanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet(), intoString:&str)
```

This would give you `str` as a "normal" optional `NSString`, which you can unwrap using the regular unwrapping operators.

Answer (score 1):

From the declaration of `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer`:

```
struct AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<T> : Equatable, LogicValue {
    let value: Builtin.RawPointer
    init(_ value: Builtin.RawPointer)
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool

    /// Access the underlying raw memory, getting and
    /// setting values.
    var memory: T
}
```

You should be able to get your string back by accessing `storingString.memory`.

What you get back should be an `NSString?` and you will have to unwrap it at that point

Comment: This works thanks! But the way of dasblinkenlight is faster. However, thanks to your answer I understand more the AutoreleasingUnsafePointer struct. I didn't catch the 'var memory: T' :)