# AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer for an NSString

Tags: swift, nsstring

I have an [AVDepthDataObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata) and I am trying to call the `dictionaryRepresentation()` function. The function takes an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>` as an argument, and I'm running into problems.

I've tried:

```
//Make a string and a pointer
let depthString: NSString = NSString()
let depthStringPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>.init(&depthString)

//Dump the depth data into the str
depthData.dictionaryRepresentation(forAuxiliaryDataType: depthStringPointer)
```

But I get an error on the `depthStringPointer` initialization saying:

> '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'RawPointer'

I'm not sure how to properly initialize the `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` for a NSString type.

I tried:

```
depthData.dictionaryRepresentation(forAuxiliaryDataType: &depthString)
```

per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205768/swift-how-to-get-the-value-from-a-autoreleasingunsafepointernsstring-from-a), but I get an error saying

> Cannot pass immutable value of type 'NSString?' as inout argument

Comment: Read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206064/1187415 to the referenced thread again. You have to declare an optional `var depthString: NSString?`, and then pass `&depthString` to the function .

Comment: Wow, okay, thank you.  I missed the 'let'/'var' difference.